# SML Difference between Val Binding and Functions

Tags: sml

```
val x = 1

fun f y =
  let
    val x = y+1
  in
    fn z => x + y + z
  end

val x = 3
val g = f 4
val y = 5
val z = g 6
```

I'm currently trying to understand function closures and lexical scope in the above code segment. In this example, why is `g` a function instead of a val binding? To my understanding, `g` is calling `f(4)` and should be bound to the return value. However, the typechecker says `g` is of type `fn : int -> int`. I'm confused as to why that is.

Comment: A function is just a special type of value. `f` is a higher-order function whose return value is itself a function, so of course `f 4` is a function. What else do you expect it to be? What is the type of `f`?

Comment: Right! I overlooked the return type of f. For some reason, I thought it returned an int. I now see that it returns a function.

Answer (score 0):

f returns a function, so the value bound to g has a function type.